# @JsonGetter doesn't work

Tags: spring, jackson

I want to make this method return `{"valid":true/false}`

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
Boolean checkUsersAvailable(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    return contentService.getUser(username) == null;
}
```

I add these annotations:

```
@JsonGetter("valid")
@JsonProperty("valid")
```

But it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a primitive type and get JSON object as a response.
You can use a wrapper or something like that:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
Map<String, Boolean> checkUsersAvailable(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    boolean result = contentService.getUser(username) == null;
    return Collections.singletonMap("success", result);
}
```

Comment: It must return Map<String,Boolean>. It ruins business logic, isn't it?

Comment: Fixed. I do not understand what you're talking about. There is no question about the business logic, the only http answer.